# Growth Rates and Stat Caps

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I'm a little fuzzy on how growth rates and stat caps work and how they interact. From what I can tell, each character has their own individual growth rates for each of their stats. This affects their chances of increasing a certain stat when they level up. For example, Unit X has a 30% growth rate for SPD. This means that whenever Unit X levels up, there's a 30% chance that the SPD stat will increase by 1. Different classes have no effect on the growth rate, so being a Barbarian or Myrmidon doesn't restrict my Avatar's MAG growth rate.

Stat caps, on the hand, vary between classes. Promoted classes (Dark Flier, Great Lord, Grandmaster, etc.) tend to have higher stat caps than their respective un-promoted classes. These stat caps describe how high you can go in a specific stat when you are in that specific class. Borrowing from my earlier example, Unit X has a stat cap of 20 for SPD in Class Y. As long as Unit X belongs to Class Y, his/her SPD cannot go above 20, no matter how much he/she levels.

*Am I understanding this correctly?*

P.S. What happens if you go from a promoted class to an un-promoted class after hitting the stat cap? I am of the understanding that your stats go down to the stat cap, but are these extra stats lost or are they regained if you raise the stat cap (by promotion or switching another class with a higher stat cap)?

Comment: Also, given that you can essentially level an infinite number of times (with repeated use of Master/Second Seals), does your class progression affects your final, final stats? Like, if I favor Myrmidons early in the game before going Mage, will I end up with lower MAG than vice-versa?

Comment: *Different classes have no effect on the growth rate, so being a Barbarian or Myrmidon doesn't restrict my Avatar's MAG growth rate.* That's not true. A character with a very low growth in mag, will have a low-to-medium growth of mag upon class changing to (dark) mage or cleric/priest/troubadour (though mages yield the higher mag-growth than clerics/priests/troubadours). Also, one thing you didn't mention, but is also important: A growth rate of (e.g.) 120% means, your character will definitely always gain 1 point in that stat, plus 20% chance of receiving an additional point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two factors at work here: The unit, and the class.

A character's current growth rates are calculated as follows:

- That Character's base growth rates (varies per character)
- +
- That Character's current class growth rates.

Likewise, a character's current stat caps are calculated as follows:

- That character's current class caps
- +
- That character's stat cap modifiers.

Additionally, there are two factors that go into calculating the actual stats:

- That character's stat level-ups
- +
- That character's class' base stats.

See the pattern?

The game tracks how many stat-ups each character has had in each stat. When you change class, you exchange caps, and class base stats. (This corresponds to the +'s and -'s on the class change screen). So despite what it might seem, you are never "losing" or "gaining" stats when you change class.

So what this means, is that while a certain class might cap your speed at 20, your unit may very well have more than 20 speed level ups, which will "reappear" if you change to a class with a higher speed cap.

The only thing I'm not sure of is if you can receive a level-up in a stat you are currently capped in. (Though obviously, you'd have to class change to see if you had)

Comment: For the children characters, I would also add the parents' stats. One thing I know for certain, is that the avatar's child will have a stat cap, depending on your avatar's "strength" or "weakness" (the strength or weakness, as defined by the player when creating the char)

Comment: @Nolonar Kind of. Children character stat caps are (Sum of Parents Stat Caps) + 1. Children character starting stats are equal to the average of (Parent 1's level ups + parent 2's level ups + child's base stats). Picking the asset / flaw for the avatar has a direct influence on the avatar's stat caps (which then gets transferred down to Morgan like the other children characters).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3nVAMzbERdMaXlHVk9hOUtZdkk/edit?usp=sharing I made a spreadsheet showing each promoted class's maximum stats (without limit break). As Raven stated, each character has modifiers that affect their maximum stats. I included story characters' stat modifiers on the second page. Your avatar's modifiers depend on which attributes you chose at the beginning, and children have the sum of their parents' modifiers +1. Morgan will not receive an additional +1 if one of his/her parents is another child. The "+" values for taguel and manakete indicate bonuses from + stones.

Comment: PS The second half of that spreadsheet includes spoilers.

Comment: I just updated that file to include Spotpass and DLC characters on the 3rd and 4th sheets.